# How to cycle an identity column's value back to 1 on reaching a limit?

Tags: sql, oracle, auto-increment, create-table

I am creating a table and I am setting an automatically generated value for it, starting from 1, but I would like this value to have a limit and then start again from 1.

In what way should I define the column for this to be like this?

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE
(
    ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1),
    NAME VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (
    ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (
        START WITH 1
        INCREMENT BY 1 
        MAXVALUE 10
        CYCLE
        NOCACHE
    ),
    NAME VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Since the `CYCLE` option is enabled, the sequence resets when it reaches the value specified in `MAXVALUE`. I added the `NOCACHE` option although that's not strictly necessary here (the only requirement is that the `CACHE` value must be smaller than `MAXVALUE`).

Here is a [DB Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=469a0bc27a0900fdbdc7438d85bfa3d9), which `MAXVAL` set to `2`: you can see that the third inserted row gets `id` `1`.

Comment: Hello GMB, I have validated the code you indicate and it works exactly as I need it